# SEO issue when migrating to wordpress – changing urls and file names etc

Tags: seo, google, url-rewriting, migration, filenames

I get an issue with the SEO of my website. Before I was on top of Google with "Icecom", but I migrated my website on WordPress. All my urls have changed and the body too...

What I did for my new SEO:

- Redirect 301
- Changing address using Google Webmaster Tool

But I don't see my website on Google anymore. What am I supposed to do?

Regards,

**Edit #1**

[image]

**Edit #2 (Index state and exploration from Google)**

[image: Index state]

[image: Exploration]

Comment: Are you allowing crawling / indexing of your site?

Comment: Yes on WordPress the checkbox to disable my website from Google is disabled. See edit#1.

Comment: What is the domain name for the site that now isn't indexed?

Comment: http://www.icecom.fr

Comment: It is indexed. Only [25 pages in Google UK](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:http:%2F%2Fwww.icecom.fr%2F) though but [47 in Google FR](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:icecom.fr). If you've lost your rankings then some part of the migration probably wasn't very smooth and your website either went down or pages weren't accessible for a period of time.

Comment: Ok, so the only way to get back my website on top is to wait? But I'm not able to see a page of my new WordPress on your links.

Comment: Potentially yes. If you have handled the 301 redirects correctly and have the same or at least 'as good as' content on your pages as you did before then any organic positions should be reinstated soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When migrating from HTML to WordPress, the main thing to be kept in mind is the permalink structure. By default HTML pages have the extension of `.html` while WordPress URLs have no extensions. (You can activate them though).

Now Google treats a `www.example.com/page.html` and `www.example.com/page` as two different URLs.

Generally, there are two options:

1. Change the Permalink structure of all pages.(There are plugins for that)
2. Redirecting using 301.

Since you have already implemented 301 redirects. So,you must know that using a 301 redirect can lead to losing 15 percent of your "link juice." Many sites quote Matt Cutts, Google’s head of Web spam, as having made that statement.

**How to avoid negative SEO because of offline website?** 
When Googlebot crawls your website while offline instead of returning an HTTP result code 404 (Not Found) or showing an error page with the status code 200 (OK) when a page is requested, it’s better to return a 503 HTTP result code (Service Unavailable) which tells search engine crawlers that the downtime is temporary. Moreover, it allows webmasters to provide visitors and bots with an estimated time when the site will be up and running again.

Comment: Before my website was using NodeJS and HTML and all my urls was like this http://mywebsite.fr/my-page and not http://mywebsite.fr/my-page.html ... And yes I already implemented 301 redirects on all urls.

Comment: Was your website offline at any moment?I am also wondering what happened.301 redirect does the work most of the times.

Comment: Yes I think 1 hour... During the migration. Does my website won't be indexed anymore?

Comment: No,it does not affect indexing in any way.You must check in Webmasters the index status of your website.I think during migration,there may have been a crawl from Google and that can affect your website in a bad way.From Google :-Once in a while we get asked whether a site’s visibility in Google’s search results can be impacted in a negative way if it’s unavailable when Googlebot tries to crawl it.

Comment: Ok see edit#2 about webmaster tools.