# When migrating a website from Joomla to WordPress, Google is not updating some metadata, description, and snippets of URLs where the content changed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, wordpress

After migrating/updating/redesign a site from Joomla to WordPress I am facing a problem that affect my SEO.

I noticed in my Webmaster Tools, Google is crawling old site urls. Some (pretty) permalinks do exist in my new web site, as a result, Google robots does not re crawl this URLs and Google search keeps the old metadata, descriptions and snippets.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO issue when migrating to wordpress – changing urls and file names etc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79685/seo-issue-when-migrating-to-wordpress-changing-urls-and-file-names-etc)

Comment: Have you 301 redirected all the old URLs to the new?

Comment: @MrWhite as far as 301 redirection from the old urls to the new site I was not able to do.The reason is that the old version site was managed by a third person and after the migration I only switch the DNS.As a result I don't know the old's site permalinks

Comment: But you presumably still have the same domain name?

Comment: You can find the old permalinks by looking in Google Search Console and your error log.   The crawl errors report in GSC will have lots of 404 URLs that you should fix.   You will find the same information in your web server error log.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the question suggested by @MrWhite.  I believe this question is very distinct from it. I have edited this question to clarify.